# How add action button to free jqgrid toolbar if fontawesome icon set is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

FontAwesome icon set is is used in free jqgrid. Default actions buttons appear as fontawesome buttons.
I tried to annd custom font avesome icon button to jqgrid row. This works for jquery ui icons:

```
        loadComplete: function() {
            var iCol = getColumnIndexByName($(this),'_actions');
            $(this).children("tbody").children("tr.jqgrow")
               .children("td:nth-child("+(iCol+1)+")")
               .each(function() {
                   $("<div>",
                     {
                         mouseover: function() {
                             $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
                         },
                         mouseout: function() {
                             $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                         },
                         click: function(e) {
                             resetSelection();
                             idsOfSelectedRows = [$(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id")];
                             $("#grid").jqGrid('setSelection', $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id"), false);
                             $('#grid_postbutton').click();
                         }
                     }
                ).css({"margin-left": "2px", float:"left"})
                 .addClass("ui-pg-div ui-inline-post")
                 // .append('<span class="ui-icon fa-lock"></span>')
                 .append('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-locked"></span>')
                 .prependTo($(this).children("div"));
```

I replaced `ui-icon-locked` with `fa-lock` using

```
   .append('<span class="ui-icon fa-lock"></span>')
```

but font awesome icon does not appear. Caret-like jquery-ui icon appears.
How to add button with font awesome icon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do almost the same things to create custom button in free jqGrid 4.8. You need just remove unneeded

```
.css({"margin-left": "2px", float:"left"})
```

and to replace

```
.append('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-locked"></span>')
```

to

```
.append('<span class="fa ui-state-default fa-fw fa-lock"></span>')
```

You can see the results on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/navButtons0-fa4-custom-action.htm):

[image]

Depend on your exact requirements you can need to use `singleSelectClickMode: "selectonly"` to prevent deselection of rows of grid on the second click on the same row.

P.S. I will consider to simplify adding of custom action button in the next version of free jqGrid.

Answer (score 1):

do it like below:

```
.append('<span class="fa fa-lock"></span>')
```